# The module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core' could not be loaded

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to run a build script from Task Scheduler on Windows Server 2012 R2 and I'm getting the following message in the Event Log after I run my job: `The module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Core'` Of course, this makes no sense since PowerShell can't be PowerShell without the Core library (and hence why I'm having trouble finding help on the Google.)

Some more information that could be relevant: 
The script is running on a computer called `VW3` and reading the script from a shared folder on `\\VW1\Developers\Continuous Integration`. The user, Build Worker, set to run the build task has all permissions on the CI folder. 
If I run the script, as the Build Worker user manually in a Powershell it executed without issue, it only fails when I run it from the Task Scheduler.
My `Start In:` folder is set to `\\VW1\Developers\Continuous Integration\`

Comment: powershell seems not to pick up on `start in` and start in the default directory (at least for me). have you considered just changing the location in your script? that is, if you get powershell to open^^ really weird error

Comment: also did you do your test (executing the script) on your local machine or actually on the remote machine? a corrupted installation is the only thing i could think of that would cause this

Comment: I've actually moved it back to a local folder on the build computer and will instead redirect the final package to the network location. I did this because of this problem, and also it seems that git has difficulty with UNC paths as well.

Comment: hmm you could try running `powershell.exe` with the -command parameter like this: -command {`New-PSDrive X -root "\\VW1\Developers\Continous Integration" -PSProvider FileSystem; . X:\Script.ps1`} if it itself works